# Why I am Getting Message at Every Click Event?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, aspxgridview

I want to display a message to a user, like this: `Duplicate Value Not Allowed`.

For that I am using `jQuery`. The first time it's working as expected, but unfortunately the one-time message is displayed every time - it's showing the same text. How can I prevent it?

.JS

```js
function OnEndCallback() {
    if (gvc.cpInsertNote == undefined || gvc.IsNewItemEditing() || gvc.IsEditing() ) {
        // Egnore   || gvc.IsNewItemEditing ||gvc.IsEditing
    }
    else {
        if (gvc.cpInsertNote != "") {
            alert(gvc.cpInsertNote);
        }
    }
    // return false;
}
```

I am Calling This Function On Grid View Updated Click

Grid:

```xml
<Templates>
    <DetailRow>
        <dx:ASPxGridView ID="dgCustomers" runat="server" KeyFieldName="CustomerLineItemID" OnBeforePerformDataSelect="dgCustomers_BeforePerformDataSelect"
        OnDataBinding="dgCustomers_DataBinding" ClientInstanceName="gvc"
        Width="100%" OnRowDeleting="dgCustomers_RowDeleting" OnRowInserting="dgCustomers_RowInserting"
        OnRowUpdating="dgCustomers_RowUpdating" CellStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ClientSideEvents EndCallback="OnEndCallback" />
                <Columns>
                    ...
```

.CS

```cs
int CustomerCount = 0;
SqlCommand cmddupCust = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from GA_LineItemsCustomers where CustomerCode = @CustomerCode and LineItemID=@LineItemID", con);
cmddupCust.Connection = con;
cmddupCust.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
cmddupCust.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerCode", CustomerCode);
cmddupCust.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LineItemID", LineItemID);
con.Open();
CustomerCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmddupCust.ExecuteScalar());
con.Close();

if (CustomerCount > 0)
{
    ((ASPxGridView)sender).JSProperties["cpInsertNote"] = "Duplicate Entries Not Allowed";
    e.Cancel = true;
    return;
}
```

Comment: In English, most words don't have capital letters, and sentences end with full stops. Questions end with question marks, and phrases end with commas. Paragraphs are also allowed. I fixed it for you. Please try to write clearly, not just in a big jumble of words. That will make it easier for other people to help you. I realise English may not be your first language, but I think the same rules apply in most other languages, too.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alert is shown based on the condition `gvc.cpInsertNote != ""`... So what about to empty it after the first alert?

```
if (gvc.cpInsertNote != "") {
  alert(gvc.cpInsertNote);
  gvc.cpInsertNote = "";  // Add this
}
```